# Matching two dataframes based on a criteria in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a query in Python pandas.

I have a two data frames:

```
 df1:
Process ID,room no,IP Address,port,status
2553,4,192.168.1.9,2,started    
2556,4,192.168.1.49,0,started
2556,2,192.168.1.25,25,started
3056,8,192.168.1.49,0,started

df2:
Process ID,room no,IP Address,port,status
2553,4,192.168.1.9,2,completed
2556,4,192.168.1.49,0,completed
2556,2,192.168.1.25,25,completed
2556,2,192.168.1.46,25,completed
3056,8,192.168.1.49,0,completed
```

I would like to remove rows from df2 based on a matching criteria with df1.

For every df2 rows that has multiple matches with df1 (based on two columns value (process ID, port)) the excess rows with (same process ID & port) in df2 should be removed.

Hope my explanation is understandable.

In short My modified df2 should look like this:

```
df2:
Process ID,room no,IP Address,port,status
2553,4,192.168.1.9,2,completed
2556,4,192.168.1.49,0,completed
2556,2,192.168.1.25,25,completed
3056,8,192.168.1.49,0,completed
```

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: My new df2 is not equal to df1. the status column is different.

Comment: This example simply removes duplicates from `df2` according to `Process ID` and `port`. A better example would help.

Comment: Can `df1`have as well multiple rows with same `Process ID` & `port`?

Comment: If you want only to remove duplicates from `df2` maybe `df2.drop_duplicates(["Process ID","port"])` is what you want.